# Cancel fadeTo effect in jquery content filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filtering, fadeto

Basically, I wish to fade out the text to certain opacity after click on the button.

I'm trying to modify the following filter effect to fadeTo() jquery. The code is taken from http://jsfiddle.net/gxfBD/33/

```
$(".filter").click( function () {
    var filterText = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
    $("li").show().not('.'+filterText).hide();
});

$(".clearfilter").click( function() {
    $("li").show();
});
```

The code has been modified to https://jsfiddle.net/Eelyn/9pw0uecz/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".filter").click( function () {
    var filterText = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
    $("li").show().not('.'+filterText).fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
});

$(".clearfilter").click( function() {
    $("li").fadeTo("slow", 1);
});
```

});

But after I changed the code, the filter function is not working. This means I cannot clear the filter using `fadeTo("slow", 1)`. Please help! Thanks!

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery website:

https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

The .fadeTo() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. It is similar to the .fadeIn() method **but that method unhides the element** and always fades to 100% opacity.

http://api.jquery.com/show/

The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation. This is **roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "block")**, except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

jQuery fadeAt doesn't do anything with the display css property. So the elements are still on the page. The show method doesn't do anything when the elements don't have display:hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/kamikazefish/gxfBD/106/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".filter").click( function () {
        var filterText = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
        $("li").fadeTo("slow", 1).not('.'+filterText).fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
    });

    $(".clearfilter").click( function() {
        $("li").fadeTo("slow", 1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Cool, working well now! Thank you very much and thanks for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

The [.fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) only changes the opacity, so you need to use fadeTo to alter the elements, not `.show`.

Also, it's better to split the groups to fade in and fade out, and apply different animations to them, this makes the filtered out `li`s fade in while other prev fade out `li`s fade in at the same time.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".filter").click( function () {
        var filter = '.' + $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
        $("li")
            .filter(filter).fadeTo("slow", 1)    // fade in those not filtered
            .end()          // Back to original set.
            .not(filter).fadeTo("slow", 0.33); // fade out those filtered.
    });

    $(".clearfilter").click( function() {
        $("li").fadeTo("slow", 1);
    });
});
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9pw0uecz/2/)

Comment: Wow, the effect is smoother and nicer by using your code. Thank you so much! :)